# Select * returning no results

Tags: sql, oracle, odbc

I am trying a simple query against an Oracle database via ODBC

```
select * 
from Table 
where Stock > 0
```

This query is returning 0 records. But there are records that exist in the table.

The column `Stock` is of `float` type. Values in `Stock` column are like 0.000, -11.000, 5.000 etc and I just need records with value more than 0.

Then I tried a different query

```
select col1, col2, col3.. 
from Table 
where Stock > 0
```

This time the execution is completed correctly and returning the expected records.

Any idea why `select *` fails and select with a column list is working fine?

Comment: The query returning zero records and a timeout are not the same thing.  What is actually happening?  Is there a timeout, or does the query complete with an empty result set?

Comment: Its not returning records . Looks like its taking more time for the completion of querry and returning 0 records back. Timeout exception is not a proper term to describe this

Comment: You should avoid using `select *` anyway - so maybe this is a small push in the right direction? ;-)

Comment: This happens only in Oracle, not in SQL

Comment: "Not in SQL" makes no sense. SQL is the query language that Oracle uses. You can't write a query without using  SQL.

Answer (score 0):

> Oracle 11gR2

**creating table**

```
create table testt
(
test_number float
);
```

**insert data :**

```
insert into testt 
select    0.5 from dual;

commit;
```

**select data**

```
select  * from
testt
where test_number>0;
```

**result :**

> TEST_NUMBER
>
> 0,5

so there is no problem with `select *`